# Iterate over elements in Rasterio window and obtain coordinates using transform.xy

Tags: arcpy, python, gdal, rasterio, numpy

Does a window generated by rasterio maintain the dataset origin and absolute col/row indices?

I'd like to be able to iterate over a window of a dem dataset, find the highest value in the window and return it's lat long coordinates using rasterio.transform.xy or similar.

Obviously the below isn't suitable (the arr is invalid), it illustrates what I'm trying to achieve. Window is generated using slices and row/col high and lows which are provided by a valid function called extract_block.

```
with rasterio.open(inputraster) as dataset:
        for (x,y) in zip(*nonzero):    
            row_low, row_high, col_low, col_high = extract_block(arr,[x,y],windowsize)
            rasteriowindowarr = dataset.read(1,window=Window.from_slices(slice(row_low, row_high), slice(col_low, col_high)))
            with rasterio.open(rasteriowindowarr) as windowarr:    
                for i,j in np.ndindex(rasteriowindowarr.shape):
                    coordinatex,coordinatey = rasterio.transform.xy(windowarr.transform, i,j,offset='center')
                    print ("long of result is " + str(coordinatex))
                    print ("lat of result is " + str(coordinatey))
```